# How do I stop PHP::memcache::delete from producing a CLIENT_ERROR?

Tags: php, memcached

If you call the following

```
$m = new Memcache()
$m->addServer('127.0.0.1')
$m->delete('key')
```

you will get

> PHP Notice:  MemcachePool::delete(): Server localhost (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: CLIENT_ERROR bad command line format.  Usage: delete  [noreply]

Answer (score 5):

As @fratrik said, passing 0 as second argument will make the function work.

But this is a workaround, the real problem is an incompatibility between the versions of the php-memcache extension and the memcache server.

It is explained [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.delete.php#98826)

Answer (score 2):

Worry not. Despite what is said at [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.delete.php), explicitly passing a timeout of `0` will fix the problem.